# Reflection Get the internal variable result value

Tags: c#

In our reporting environment we have a method to get the DataSources, which is looking like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ReportDataSource> GetDataSources(IEnumerable<ReportParameter> parameters)
{
    return new List<ReportDataSource>
    {
        new ReportDataSource("DataSource1", GetDataSource1(parameters)),
        new ReportDataSource("DataSource2", GetDataSource2(parameters))
    };
}
```

The values from the methods called are just ICollections. My problem is, I need to know the internal Type of these collections for documentation-purposes, at best without having to invoke the method. I just need the calls they're making, I broke this down to the local variable via:

```
const string dataSourcesMethodName = "GetDataSources";

MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(
    dataSourcesMethodName,
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    Type.DefaultBinder,
    new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<ReportParameter>) },
    null);

    var methodBody = methodInfo.GetMethodBody();
    var variable = methodBody.LocalVariables.First(f => f.LocalType == typeof(IEnumerable<ReportDataSource>));
```

Is it even possible to get the information I need without invoking this method?

Comment: If you look at the source code, what does `GetDataSource1(parameters)` returns? Because if it returns a `ICollection<something>`, it is easy to extract the `something`... But if it returns a `ICollection`, it is nearly impossible to discover what it is doing.

Comment: Sadly Just an ICollection, but I guess the variable-type has this informations?

Comment: Only the members within that collection have this information, as you may store evrything within it.

Comment: @matthias No http://goo.gl/8QN19K See the IL code on the right.

Comment: Well, thanks for clarification, I will just fake the data and compile it then I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you can't without executing the method... some examples (see http://goo.gl/8QN19K):

C#:

```
public ICollection M1() {
    ICollection col = new List<string>();
    return col;
}

public ICollection M2() {
    ArrayList col = new ArrayList();
    col.Add("Hello");
    return col;
}
```

IL code locals:

```
.locals init (
    [0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.ICollection,
    [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.ICollection
)
```

and

```
.locals init (
    [0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.ArrayList,
    [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.ICollection
)
```

Compiling in Release mode it is even worse, the locals could totally  disappear... See for example http://goo.gl/yvWZHR

In general those methods could use for example an `ArrayList`, so an untyped collection (as in the `M2` method). Good luck finding the type of its elements without executing the method and parsing some elements.

Comment: Well, was worth a try I guess, thanks for clarifiying